# Prove $\alpha(x,y) = (x(x^2+y^2), y(x^2 + y^2), x^2 + y^2)$ has a continuous inverse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Let $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\alpha(x,y) = (x(x^2+y^2), y(x^2 + y^2), x^2 + y^2)$.  How do I show that $\alpha$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to its image, it has a continuous inverse - ie. $\alpha^{-1}: \alpha(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous?

This was given as an example in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, regarding a function that was almost a coordinate patch (it fails to be due to the rank of the matrix $D\alpha (x)$ failing to be of rank 2 at 0), but I can't seem to prove rigourously why the inverse should in fact be continuous.

Comment: So what is your map $\alpha^{-1}$?

Comment: Here's my progress so far: Let $\alpha(\mathbb{R}) = M$.  I know $\alpha^{-1}$ needs to be such that it maps $(x(x^2+y^2), y(x^2+y^2), x^2 + y^2)$ to $(x,y)$.  So my attempt was to let $\alpha^{-1} = g \circ i$, where $i: M \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is the inclusion map (which is continuous) and $g: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $g(a, b, c) = (\frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{c})$ for $c \neq 0$ and $g(a, b, c) = (0, 0)$ for $c = 0$.  Then $g \circ i$ is indeed the inverse of $\alpha$ and we're almost done but $g$ is not globally continuous - in specific $g$ is not continuous when $c = 0$.

Comment: Cool. What equation relating $a,b,c$ holds on $M$?

Comment: Ah I didn't think of this until I saw your comment.  On $M$, we have $a^2 + b^2 = c^3$.  Then using this, I can prove that if we consider $g: M \to \mathbb{R}^2$, then $g$ is in fact continuous at $(0, 0 ,0)$ as follows: let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and consider $\delta < \epsilon^{3}$.  Then if $(a,b,c) \in M$ and $||(a,b,c)|| < \delta$ then we have $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} = \sqrt{c^2(c+1)} = c \sqrt{c+1}< \delta$.  Since $\sqrt{c} < \sqrt{1+c}$ we have $c^{3/2} < \delta$ or $\sqrt{c} < \delta^{1/3}$.

Comment: Then $||g(a,b,c)|| = ||(\frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{c})|| = \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2}} = \sqrt{c}$ (where the last equality comes from $a^2 + b^2 = c^3$) and so this is less than $\delta^{1/3} = \epsilon$.

Comment: This proves continuity of $g$ on $M$ and so we have our claim, correct?

Comment: Much appreciated @TedShifrin - this was fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is fine. Just to finish this off slightly differently, note that $M$ is a (topological) $2$-dimensional manifold parametrized by $(a,b)$. I.e., $M= \{(a,b,c): c=(a^2+b^2)^{1/3}\}$. Now, for $(a,b,c)\in M$ with $c\ne 0$,
$$\alpha^{-1}(a,b,c) = \left(\frac ac,\frac bc\right) = \frac1{(a^2+b^2)^{1/3}}(a,b).$$
Note that
$$\left\|\frac{(a,b)}{(a^2+b^2)^{1/3}}\right\| = \frac{(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}}{(a^2+b^2)^{1/3}} = (a^2+b^2)^{1/6},$$
whose limit as $(a,b)\to (0,0)$ is clearly $0$. (Yes, if $\|(a,b)\|<\delta$, then $\|\alpha^{-1}(a,b,c)\|<\delta^{1/3}$, as you said.)